# What is the fastest, most error-free method of extracting and cleaning the HTML body text in Python?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, lxml, text-processing

I currently have two functions to extract the HTML `<body>` text from Python and return it as a bag of words.  They give equivalent output.  I also clean up various tags that would otherwise give me garbage text (e.g. `<script>` code).

```
def html_to_bow_bs(text):
    if text is None or len(text)==0:
        return []

    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "lxml",parse_only=SoupStrainer('body'))

    # Remove all irrelevant tags
    for elem in soup.findAll(['script','style','a']):
        elem.extract()
    body_text = soup.findAll("body")
    if len(body_text) == 0:
        return []

    # Encoding.  Remove extra whitespace and unprintable characters
    the_text = body_text[0].get_text().encode('utf-8')
    the_text = str(the_text)
    the_text = the_text.strip()
    the_text = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+',' ',the_text)
    return [w.lower() for w in the_text.split()]




def html_to_bow_bs_lxml(text):
    if text is None or len(text)==0:
        return []
    body_re = re.findall('<body(.*?)</body>', text, flags=re.DOTALL)
    if len(body_re) == 0:
        return []
    fragment = body_re[0]

    # Remove irrelevant tags
    fragment = re.sub(r'<script.*?</script>', ' ', fragment, flags=re.DOTALL)
    fragment = re.sub(r'<style.*?</style>', ' ', fragment, flags=re.DOTALL)
    text = "<body" + fragment + "</body>"
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "lxml")

    if soup is None:
        return []

    # Remote more irrelevant tags
    for elem in soup.findAll(['a']):
        elem.extract()

    # Encoding.  Remove extra whitespace and unprintable characters
    the_text = body_text[0].get_text().encode('utf-8')
    the_text = str(the_text)
    the_text = the_text.strip()
    the_text = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+',' ',the_text)
    return [w.lower() for w in the_text.split()]
```

My main requirement is matching output: that the set of words from `html_to_bow_bs_lxml(text)` matches `html_to_bow_bs(text)`. Currently, both are on a par on running time; for 330 pages, they run about 20 seconds (slow!).  If I remove and replace my last `soup.findAll(['a'])...extract()` in my second function with regexes, I can shave 6 seconds off my time.  Replacing `BeautifulSoup` altogether with `lxml.etree` can shave an additional 10 seconds, making the total run time about 3-4 seconds.  However, when replacing the with regexes,

1. the output doesn't always match.  When replacing `BeautifulSoup` either the output doesn't match or
2. my program crashes during processing because of poorly-formed HTML.  How to increase speed while maintaining correctness?

I've seen various recommendations for extracting HTML with Python generally on StackOverflow, but these date back a few years (e.g. 2012).  There have understandably been many updates to the libraries since then.

(I've also tried pyquery, but it doesn't always extract the body correctly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've done a lot to make it fast - the soup strainer and the `lxml` parser are usually the first things to try when optimizing the parsing with `BeautifulSoup`.

Here are some improvements to this particular code.

Remove the body existence check:

```
body_text = soup.findAll("body")
if len(body_text) == 0:
    return []
```

and use `find()` instead.

Replace the `if text is None or len(text)==0:` with just `if not text:`.

Strip via `get_text(strip=True)`.

---

The improved code:

```
def html_to_bow_bs(text):
    if not text:
        return []

    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "lxml", parse_only=SoupStrainer('body'))

    # Remove all irrelevant tags
    for elem in soup.find_all(['script','style','a']):
        elem.extract()

    body = soup.find("body")
    if not body:
        return []

    the_text = body.get_text(strip=True).encode('utf-8')
    the_text = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+', ' ', the_text)
    return [w.lower() for w in the_text.split()]
```

These are just micro-improvements and I don't think they are gonna change the overall performance picture. What I would also look into:

- running the script via `pypy` (`beautifulsoup4` is [compatible](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/compatibility/wiki/beautiful_soup), but you would not be able to use `lxml` parser - try it with `html.parser` or `html5lib`). You might win a lot without even modifying the code at all.

Comment: Thanks!  It looks like there were some incremental improvements.  However, `body.get_text(strip=True)` gave very much fewer words than separating `get_text()` and `strip()` into two different functions.  I replaced that with `' '.join([text for text in body.stripped_strings]).encode('utf-8')` gives more words that were actually missed by my approaches.  This edit, along with the above, give nearly equal runtime performance though.

Comment: @Matt yeah, thanks, I was not expecting much of a performance boost from these changes. What about the pypy?

Comment: Currently trying it now.  Sorry, was running out of comment space. :)

Comment: Wow, pypy gave me a very impressive performance boost, by half.  Unfortunately, it's not compatible with some of my other libraries (`pandas` for data analysis), but I'm going to mark this as the solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using requests module and bs4

This is a simplest way to print the main text.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "yourUrl"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
items = soup.find_all('body')
for item in items:
    print item.text
```

Note: If you print all body, it also would print jquery and javascript functions in case there are in there.

Comment: Unfortunately, since jQuery and JavaScript would be included in the output, this doesn't meet the above specs.  We can also assume the HTML text is input to the functions, so `import requests` isn't necessary.